# Sharing my screen in Teams randomly adds random color over my whole screen

Tags: windows-11, gpu, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-teams

When I share my screen from Teams my participants see a magenta or green color overlayed randomly across the content I'm sharing. Not constantly, but with flashes. It's very distracting.

This is what it looks like (images made with photoshop as it's hard to press print-screen at the exact right time):

[image]
[image]

Managed to capture it live in the New teams client:

[image]

[Here's a video that shows the issue while it happens](https://photos.app.goo.gl/XmDkuLDts6LEYBt68).

I can easily reproduce the issue:

1. Start a call from the Teams client (new or classic) and join my main workstation (AMD ThreadRipper 2950X with AMD RX 6750X video card)
2. Join the call from another system using the windows Teams client (classic or new)
3. Join the call from another system using the Linux or Web Teams client
4. From the main workstation (1) start screensharing.
5. If the issue doesn't appear stop screen sharing and start again.
6. The users joining from the web client and windows client will not get random flashes of color overlayed over the shared screen.
7. Not all users see the same flashes at the same time.

The main workstation remains unaffected, it doesn't see any artifacts.

I cannot reproduce the issue while sharing screen from my laptop which has a very similar configuration: AMD Ryzen 9, AMD RX 6500M.

A screen capture utility (snagit) on the affected systems also doesn't capture the artifacts. Taking a screenshot (<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>) at the exact right time will work.

I've already tried:

- resetting my graphic drivers
- clearing Teams' cache and settings folders
- reinstalling Teams completely
- sharing the screen an app or a region doesn't seem to matter
- replaced the graphics card from an older AMD RX580 GPU to an AMD RX 6750 XT
- and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and `sfc /scannow`
- all video effects & background blur is turned off.
- Changed the GPU support settings in Windows and AMD Adrenalin.
- set `disablegpu: true` in the `%Appdata%\Microsoft\Teams\desktop-config.json` config file.
- Reset all my video codecs to system default.
- uninstalled the video driver and using Windows-default
- reinstalled the latest AMD Adrenalin Edition
- tried with camera and sound disabled.
- installed latest K-lite codec pack with recommended settings
- deleted and reinstalled teams completely
- Tried Teams New and Teams Classic

**Most important datapoint**

- **The issue occurs when one of the participants is using the Web or Linux client.**

Comment: If you have an HDR monitor, try turning the HDR setting off in Windows to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: My screens do not support HDR.

Comment: Weird problem. Try to test Windows integrity on that computer by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: No faults found

Comment: Is there any effect when setting "Show Background Effects"?

Comment: Video effects, Background filters and background images are turned off. The video is straight from my Brio webcam.

Comment: I've just added Teams to my graphics custom settings and configured it to use "GPU High Performance". Not sure yet if that fixes things.

Comment: I just reset my media encoder filters in windows using this tool. It found a few inconsistencies and removed a couple of misconfigured codecs. https://www.trishtech.com/2022/11/fix-broken-codecs-on-windows-with-codec-tweak-tool/ hoping this will work... Waiting for the next opportunity to see artifacts.

Comment: I suggest installing a codec pack. I use [KLite](https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) which also does a check of all the existing codecs during its installation.

Comment: I don't really want any non-default codecs as in just messes things up. I use VLC for playing, which comes with its own codecs and handbrake for encoding, which carrier its own codecs. Just to prevent these kinds of issues.

Comment: Your problem is rather with Teams, which uses the installed codecs. Your already installed codecs are almost all third-party software, in any case, so some more couldn't hurt. The KLite installation may include player software, but this is an installation option that can be disabled.

Comment: Have you tried in Teams to disable GPU Hardware Acceleration?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the 64bit version of Teams, rather than the 32bit ?

Comment: @1NN I'm on Windows 11 64 bit and running Teams 64 bit (both classic and new)

Comment: @harrymc that option doesn't exist in the new Teams client. Turning it off in Windows and the AMD configuration tool did not make a difference.

Comment: Here's a related thread: try to do what they propose: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/microsoft-teams-screen-sharing-during-meeting/29a0856c-4894-4d20-af1d-61fb75a0bc5f

Comment: That's on the host's system. In my case only the people wachting see the problem. And I can observe it by logging in from a 2nd system. Clearing caches hasn't solved anything.

Comment: You said 'The issue occurs when one of the participants is using the Web or Linux client.'. Questions: 1)are only the web/linux participants seeing the defect or everyone (including those on PC/mac/smartphone)? 2)if its only web/linux participants why do you believe the issue is on your PC, maybe its glitch with those teams-clients? I mean I guess it could be something unique to your screen share could try changing resolution, DPI, frequency/refresh-rate stopping then starting screen share again

Comment: @gregg the issue happens on *all* users when a web or linux user joins the call. Even if I join the call from a 2nd browser on the *same* system that's hosting the call.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try to replicate it on my end. If you are a licensed/paid teams user I suggest you reach out to Microsoft, the fact that the screen share LOOKS fine UNTIL a web/linux user joins makes me 100% believe its something in Teams client/infrastructure. I would try this exact scenario in Zoom as there is always finger-pointing & if your same PC has no issue in zoom with a user join on zoom website kind of points 100% to teams

Comment: Zoom has no issues, nor has cisco's WebEx.

Comment: (1) Does the Linux user use the latest Teams version? The latest version is [here](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux). (2) The linux user could also try [MS-Teams-background-changer](https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/MS-Teams-background-changer).

Comment: @harrymc yups latest everything. Tried multiple browsers as well. But it doesn't matter whether it's Linux. If I join using the web client from my work laptop or from my workstation in Windows, the same thing happens. If I join that same call using the Teams client, the issue doesn't occur.

Comment: You mean that the symptom is that a mixture of web and desktop on the same chat causes background color glitches? For both types or only for one?

Comment: You mention webcam try turning that off to see if it has any effect while browser/linux participant is joined then stop share then reshare. I am not able to replicate on Win10: -New Teams app v23257.2618.2432.4374; client v49/24010419130; Win10 Enterprise v22H2 64-bit; -i5-1135G7 built-in Iris XE graphic; joined from browser (Edge v110.0.1587.63) on another PC & user; joined from Firefox (v122.0.1) on same PC sharing screen

Comment: I can confirm disable GPU doesn't seem to be anywhere in 'new' Teams. Looks like you may be able to edit: `%Appdata%\Microsoft\Teams\desktop-config.json` change `"disableGpu":false` to true; [source](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-virtual-apps-desktops/multimedia/opt-ms-teams.html). Other ideas for GFX settings in Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-fix-app-audio-and-gpu-issues-for-immersive-spaces-ac05db96-aa26-4fe2-baf2-152b0edc0522#bkmk_enable-dedicated-gpu-usage

Comment: Tried both with `"disableGpu":false` and `"disableGpu":true` (which was the current setting). No difference.

Comment: Camera on or off makes no difference, Sound on or off or even completely disabled makes no difference.

Comment: Is this caused by a mixture of web and desktop on the same chat? For both types or only for one?

Comment: @harrymc Again, while screensharing from the Teams client (classic or new), when a webclient joins the call it causes these color artifacts for all participants in the call. The host doing the screensharing does *not* see any of it. Not all participants see the same color artifacts at the same time, but all are impacted. Here is a video of 1 client (web, edge win11) having it very bad while the other (team new, win11) doesn't seem to be affected: https://photos.app.goo.gl/XmDkuLDts6LEYBt68 (the new teams client is affected, just shows a lot fewer artifacts).

Comment: @jessehouwing: This is clearer. Every post I could find counseled to disable GPU Hardware Acceleration, so I added an answer with a method that might fix it for Windows clients.

Comment: I've opened a premium support ticket with Office 365 support, but so far, they're coming up empty too. So far the GPU hardware acceleration setting isn't fixing anything for this specific bug though. While it may fix other problems (I've seen quite a few in my search for a solution so far), please don't add an answer that doesn't actually work for this problem. It's hard enough to try all the options as is. I think it's a true bug in Teams itself. I do really appreciate your help so far, even if it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There currently isn't a good answer to this question.

The issue has successfully been reproduced with Office 365 Premium Support and after walking through all the already tried solutions, escalated to the Teams Engineering team.

They confirm that none of the options above seem to work and hope to provide a fix or solution soon.